# System.out and final object inlining

Tags: java

As we all know javac inlines constants at compile time which can lead to interesting problems when only recompiling parts of an application and everyone here knows the usual solution to this (make it so that javac doesn't understand it's actually a compile time constant)

But if we look at the code in `System.class` of the oracle JDK we see the following:

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

So presumably `out` is set by reflection or some other mechanism in the JVM initialization. But this leads to the question: Why isn't out being inlined here? (at least I have never gotten a null pointer exception when using `System.out.println()`).

Does javac special case that scenario or is this actually handled by the language spec sensibly?

Comment: only literals 'consts' are inlined, the rest are read each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple outcomes of `static final` construct. Literals might be inlined
for instance `static final int xxx = 1`, as that's clear but for instance `static final int xxx = returnOne()` may not be.

Primitive types and String can be replaced with literals only, all other objects may not. Last but not least `System.out/in` violate JLS ( *Once a final field has been initialized, it always contains the same value.* ).

Few ways to prevent inline: `static final String xxx="xxx".intern();` or `static final int yyy=123+return0();` since the evaluation may be performed only during runtime the javac will generate GETFIELD and not BIPUSH (for int).

Comment: Interesting - can't find the definition in the JLS but limiting it to literals and Strings would explain why it works without those hacks. And yes I do know how to avoid inlining for strings and ints - I just stumbled upon it in the code and was surprised that it worked without those hacks.

Comment: The very first  (and only) book i read (on java) "java secrets" was talking about that peculiarity, also it's quite obvious since the only way to inline anything is either BIPUSH or a constant table reference (I got that a bit later while learning the "java assembler")

Answer (score 1):

My JDK code says `out = nullInputStream()` with comment on that method:

```
/**
 * The following two methods exist because in, out, and err must be
 * initialized to null. The compiler, however, cannot be permitted to
 * inline access to them, since they are later set to more sensible values
 * by initializeSystemClass().
 */
```

And `initializeSystemClass()` calls `setOut0(..)` which is `native` and probably goes around the `final`. `System.setOut(..)` works the same way.

Comment: Interesting - is this the OpenJDK variant? I'm using the oracle/sun implementation.

Comment: @Voo, setIn and setOut are present since 1.1 (i.e. since forever for most people) in all JDK versions... far earlier than java become a GPL compliant.

Comment: @bestsss But bozho's code is using `out = nullInputStream()` while it says `out = null` for me which is different. How the final variable is overwritten isn't interesting - I know that there are several different ways. Seems like the writers of that code also didn't know the limitation to only literals and strings in the JLS ;)

Comment: @Voo, I do not recall a single version w/ `out=null` and `in=null`, but that field cannot be replaced with a constant since it's not a String, also JVM use intrinsics for System.in/out to read 'em each time (no CSE [Common Subexpression Elimination] for them)

Comment: @bestsss Now I'm somewhat interested in finding out from which parallel universe the source listing of my JDK is coming ;) Downloaded it as usual from oracle when setting up the machine.. Yep lazy initialization of finals and CSE by the JIT is another bag of problems, which is rather similar. The "bugfix" would be the same in both cases.

Comment: @Voo, java7 by chance, no experience with (aside G1 native leaking which makes it useless)

Comment: @bestsss Yep Java7 - seems they "fixed" it there.